# Kestrel server reverse proxy with apache and nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, asp.net-core, .net-core, reverse-proxy

I have followed the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to host .NET core 2.1 on AWS AMI ec2. I have configured reverse proxy as below

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ErrorLog hellomvc-error.log
    CustomLog hellomvc-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access my web site/web api, it is redirecting me to https://ip:5001 and giving error "site cant be reached"

The same issue is with nginx with following configuration

```
server {
    listen        80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your config for your app?

Comment: There is no issue with config. App is running in local debug (kestrel/IIS Express). I am facing this issue when using app.UseHttpsRedirection(). Commenting this line , app browsing/proxy is working fine. Is this because I do not have SSL setup in ec2 ami ?

Comment: @A_____  This happened to me, in my case it was related to the AWS EC2 instance, I forgot to add a rule to open 443 port to allow HTTPS traffic.